RasterLayer style changes depending on BBOX
I have many RasterLayers with this Style
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><sld:StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" version="1.0.0">
  <sld:NamedLayer>
    <sld:Name>Default Styler</sld:Name>
    <sld:UserStyle>
      <sld:Name>Default Styler</sld:Name>
      <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <sld:Name>name</sld:Name>
        <sld:Rule>
          <sld:MinScaleDenominator>10000.1</sld:MinScaleDenominator>
          <sld:MaxScaleDenominator>17500.0</sld:MaxScaleDenominator>
          <sld:RasterSymbolizer>
            <sld:ContrastEnhancement/>
          </sld:RasterSymbolizer>
        </sld:Rule>
      </sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
    </sld:UserStyle>
  </sld:NamedLayer>
</sld:StyledLayerDescriptor>

When I make a WMS Request, the style is changing depending on the bbox.
This Tiles are next to each other:


The color should not change at all. I tried removing ContrastEnhancement and RasterSymbolizer but it didn't work.

If you want a fixed colour ramp then you will need to specify it otherwise Geoserver will automatically stretch your visible pixel values.

Hi Ian, thanks for your fast reply :)So, if I want geoserver to not do anything with my raster layer and show it as it is - just restricted to some scale + maybe opacity, I need to defined a ColorMap for everything? We are generating this SLDs automatically - is there a generic ColorMap that would not change anything?
